# Не пробрасываются порты в docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose

Я новичок в docker-compose. Мне для работы нужен PHP и Mysql.
Я создал себе простой файл docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ""
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:3306:3306
  php:
    image: php:7.4-fpm
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:8080:80
```

который прекрасно работает внутри контейнеров
а из PHPSTORM не могу подключиться к базе
Пробовал указывать хост как 192.168.99.100 так и 127.0.0.1 пользователь root пароль пустое поле

не подключается

Пробовал в браузере заходить на 192.168.99.100:8080 и на 127.0.0.1:8080 и на localhost:8080 не доступна страница
Подскажите что нужно сделать, чтобы я смог на своей машине подключиться к базе данных и чтобы по адресу localhost:8080 я бы смог увидеть ответ от nginx?

```
Windows 8.1 Профессиональная

docker-machine url tcp://192.168.99.100:2376

docker-compose ps
Системе не удается найти указанный путь.
    Name                  Command              State                  Ports
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
docker_db_1    docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld     Up      127.0.0.1:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
docker_php_1   docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm   Up      127.0.0.1:8080->80/tcp, 9000/tcp

docker-compose exec php /bin/bash
root@b893e16fdbd8:/var/www/html# php -v
PHP 7.4.11 (cli) (built: Oct 13 2020 10:09:45) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что докер у вас не на локальной машине поднят? тогда вам нужно указывать не 127.0.0.1, так как это работает только локально, а IP сервера. либо пробрасывать порты через SSH тоннель

Comment: на локальной машине развернут через docker tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Если это только локальная разработка, то уберите указание IP из портов

> 

```
ports:

 - 3306:3306
```

Соответственно еще стоит посмотреть лог контейнера, возможно он что-то там напишет про порты. Еще возможно порты надо обернуть в кавычки "3306:3306"

2. Не очень понятно, почему вы ожидаете ответа от nginx, если запускаете контейнер просто с php-fpm :) Поднимайте еще контейнер с nginx, связывайте его с php-контейнером, а порт 8080 прокидывайте в контейнере nginx, а не php. Тогда ответ будет.